# Ext JS, item click listener does't seem to work

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid panel which shows all my users from my database. 
I want my grid items(rows) to be clickable, as something to happen when i click on them but it doesn't seem like the listener is ok.

```
    Ext.define('PRJ.view.Home', {
     extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
     alias: 'widget.home',
     title: 'Home',
     layout: 'fit',

     items: [
        {
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            store: 'Users',
            title: 'Users grid',
            columns: [
                {text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'id' },
                {text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', width : 200 }
            ]
        }
    ]

    });


    Ext.define('PRJ.controller.Menu', {
     extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

     refs: [
         {
            ref: 'centerPanel',
            selector: '#center-panel'
        }
     ],
     stores: ["Users"
     ],


     init: function() {
         this.control({
             'gridpanel': {
                 itemdblclick: this.editUser
             }
         });
     },

     editUser: function() {
         alert('User double clicked');
     },
});
```

Comment: I'm note quite sure, but I think the scope within `this.control is` different, means you may try sth. like `init: function() {var me = this; this.control({'gridpanel': {itemdblclick: me.editUser}});},`

Comment: Does the call to `control` even run?

Comment: how can i check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may just be as simple as changing itemdblclick to rowdblclick.

I have created a fiddle [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/gj9) showing a slightly different approach (by adding listeners in the config). Code below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        title: 'Simpsons',
        store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
        columns: [{
            text: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name'
        }, {
            text: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            flex: 1
        }, {
            text: 'Phone',
            dataIndex: 'phone'
        }],
        listeners: {
            rowdblclick: function(grid, record, tr, rowIndex, e, eOpts) {
                alert(record.get("name"));
            }
        },
        height: 200,
        width: 400,
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

You should also look at [Selection Model](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.Model) and [Row Editing](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing).

Answer (score 1):

You can use cell editing plugin to make cells editable on click.
Include something like this in your grid conf : 
plugins: [
                        Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                            clicksToEdit: 1,
                            pluginId: 'cellEditor'
                        })
                    ]

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was.
The answers I got were not helping, because I needed to keep the listener in the controller instead of moving it to the view.

The problem was that I needed to put the listener on `home gridpanel` like

```
init: function() {
     this.control({
         'home gridpanel': {
             itemdblclick: this.editUser
         }
     });
 },
```

Now it works like charm.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Making the selector more specific won't solve the problem you were having. If it matches `home gridpanel` then it also matches `gridpanel`. I highly doubt this is correct, you probably changed something else (including the controller correctly).

Comment: I haven't changed anything else..  If you want i can paste the code that now runs corectly.